# Health Risks Associated with Working in Chemistry Labs

Tags: safety

I've been working in a contaminants food quality lab for about 2 years now and was curious what the chronic health effects would be, should I be worried about cancer?

Comment: I think this is far too broad. We don't know what chemicals you are exposed to on a daily basis, how much exposure you get, etc. etc. Obviously as chemists we try to minimise such risks but without a lot more details I'm not sure if anybody can really say anything useful.

Comment: I work on several different methods, I work with actonitrile, cyclohexane, residual solvents, and volatiles (containing aromatics) quite often

Comment: Thinking about safety is the key consideration. Frankly people are terrible at assessing risks. There are 50,000 deaths in car accidents every year. There are not nearly that many chemists dying from lab accidents.  You're in more risk driving to work that you are in the lab. Are you going to stop driving and traveling in a car too?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the MSDS information for anything that you work with specifically and/or researching the long term health effects of those specific substances

Comment: I have, I just wasnt sure on a timeline of how long it would take to develop chronic illnesses, I'm currently trying to get out of the lab even though i love it.